# Hashear un password en asp.net core 3.1 mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Mi clase con el metodo HasehdPassword

```
    {
        byte[] salt = new byte[128 / 8];
        using (var rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create())
        {
            rng.GetBytes(salt);
        }

        string hashed = Convert.ToBase64String(KeyDerivation.Pbkdf2(
            password: password,
            salt: salt,
            prf: KeyDerivationPrf.HMACSHA256,
            iterationCount: 10000,
            numBytesRequested: 256 / 8));

        return new HashedPassword() { Password = hashed, Salt = Convert.ToBase64String(salt) };
    }
```

Lo mando llamar en mi controller

```
    public IActionResult NewPassword(PasswordViewModel 
                                     passwordViewModel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View();
        }

        var hash = HashHelper.Hash(miHashedPass.PasswordHash);
        miHashedPass.PasswordHash = hash.Password;

        miHashedPass.PasswordHash = passwordViewModel.Password;

        _context.Update(miHashedPass);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        return View();
    }
```

Pero dentro de mi controller no me funciona, quiero que cuando el usuario introduzca su contraseña se guarde de la forma hasheada dentro de mi tabla en la base de datos.